# Archive build is crashing on launch

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

Can anybody help me out, I'm getting error on app launch with archive build. Debug build is working fine.

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xffffffffffffffe8

VM Regions Near 0xffffffffffffffe8:
--> shared memory          00007fffffe36000-00007fffffe37000 [    4K] r-x/r-x SM=SHM  


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff8fb6c4f1 std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool) + 29
1   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff8fb6e437 std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::tellg() + 191
2   ???                             0x000000010d0b44ee 0 + 4513809646
3   ???                             0x000000010d0b35d8 0 + 4513805784
4   ???                             0x000000010d1213cd 0 + 4514255821
5   ???                             0x000000010d18e5c7 0 + 4514702791
6   ???                             0x000000010d159251 0 + 4514484817
7   ???                             0x000000010d18df0a 0 + 4514701066
8   ???                             0x000000010d144b1a 0 + 4514401050
9   ???                             0x000000010d0b121a 0 + 4513796634
10  ???                             0x000000010d0b66b1 0 + 4513818289
11  dyld                            0x00007fff659f1d0b ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 265
12  dyld                            0x00007fff659f1e98 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
13  dyld                            0x00007fff659ee891 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 305
14  dyld                            0x00007fff659ee718 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 138
15  dyld                            0x00007fff659ee989 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 75
16  dyld                            0x00007fff659e1245 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 187
17  dyld                            0x00007fff659e4c19 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2669
18  dyld                            0x00007fff659e0276 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 512
19  dyld                            0x00007fff659e0036 _dyld_start + 54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to library image not loaded in release build. I didn't added library in 'Linked Binary With Libraries'.